# Finding a range for a common mode signal

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, differential, npn

I have the question below

[image: Question 9.32 part 1 from "Microelectronic Circuits" by Sedra/Smith, 7th edition]

[image: Question 9.32 part 2 from "Microelectronic Circuits" by Sedra/Smith, 7th edition]

Here is the figure they are talking about:

[image: Figure 9.14 from "Microelectronic Circuits" by Sedra/Smith, 7th edition]

(Text and images from: ["Microelectronic Circuits" book by Sedra/Smith, 7th edition, chapter 9](http://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/9780199339136/))

Here are the answers to the problem from the book

[image: Answer to Question 9.32 from "Microelectronic Circuits" by Sedra/Smith, 7th edition]

Now here is my analysis
PART A:
the largest input common mode is V_cm,max

\begin{equation}
V_{CB}=0=V_C-V_B\\V_C=V_{cm,max}\\therefore\\V_{cm,max}=V_{CC}-\frac{\alpha I}{2}R_C
\end{equation}

which is correct for part A. Now, for part B, am getting really confused.
Here is my analysis for part B:

\begin{equation}
-1<V_{cm}<1\\V_{cm,max}=1\\V_{R_C}=\frac{\alpha I}{2}R_C\\V_{cm,max}=V_{CC}-V_{R_C}\\V_{R_C}=V_{CC}-V_{cm,max}=2-1=1V
\end{equation}

But the book says that V_RC=2V. Can somebody please tell me how??

Comment: Just use your answer for (a) and remember what you are solving for. Their answer arrives, trivially.

Comment: Raykh - As mentioned on one of your earlier questions, can you please add a reference for the book where you are getting those questions (book title, author(s), edition and page number)? It will help future readers who are looking for help with the same book. (And please also add these references for any other questions which you ask about from books or websites, from now onwards.) Thanks.

Comment: @jonk, so basically your just saying to rearrange the equation from part a. Well on this case how would this affect the fact that vcm is between +/-1. Thank you for your comment and your help in advance

Comment: I don't want to argue with you or your book. If you don't think the authors arrived at their answer after that fashion, I will simply accept that you are in a better position to know.

Comment: @jonk, I am not here to make an argument. I am simply thanking you for taking the time to offer the help. Secondly am just here to learn. I was just wondering on how could the fact that putting VCR at 2 votls would make vcm between +/-1. Again thank you for your help

Comment: @Raykh With you, I will always be very careful. Prior discussions are not forgotten. Do you *understand* your own work on solving (a)? I guess I'm perhaps a little flummoxed about why you don't follow what you yourself wrote out. Do you follow that half of \$I\$ goes through each collector leg? Do you not notice that (b) is asking about \$I\: R_c\$ and is ***not*** asking about \$\frac12 I\: R_c\$? It seems kind of obvious to me. But it's your book and your experiences and I have to accept you know the book better than I.

Answer (score 0):

1. Given Vcc = 2V,
2. Find a value of IRc, e.g. find (Ie1 + Ie2) * Rc,
3. Such that common-mode input signal can be -1V to +1V

I've sourced my review of this subject from [here.](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/412/handouts/7.3%20The%20BJT%20differntial%20pair/section%207_3%20The%20BJT%20Differential%20Pair%20lecture.pdf) Also, I've taken to using some of the symbols therein and shortened some of the conclusions that I copied here.

We can express the two small-signal components in terms of their average (**common-mode**)
Vcm = (V1 + V2)/2
or their **differential-mode**
Vd = V1 - V2

Here's where the "trivially" comment comes in.  The common mode signal should have 1V of mobility up or down when your source is 2V.  There is precisely 1 point where that mobility is possible, biasing the collector at 1V.  
If you're still wondering why 2V, notice the equation has both emitter currents over one resistor Rc.  Divide that current over two identical resistors and it halves the voltage.

Assume that by "common-mode input signal" they mean applied to both bases (common-mode) and input signal (differential of the two voltages).  Assume that Vcm cannot be less than 0 or more than Vcc.  Assume that \$|v_{C1} - v_{C2}|\$ must always be less than about 1.75V (Vth).

Please try to take action on the comments.  They have correctly asked you to provide more context to the question you have asked.

**Edit:**
As relates to your comment and direct question:  Choose I*Rc such that common mode input is +- 1V.  It appears they're asking you to choose a saturation voltage (all the current goes left OR right) such the input range is supported.  2V power supply is given and a swing of +- 1V, the swing is 2\$V_{pp}\$ , so the saturation voltage \$IR_c\$ must = \$V_{cc}\$

Comment: can I say that \begin{equation}V_{R_C}=1V\:=\:\frac{1}{2}IR_C\:therefore\:IR_C=2V_{R_C}=2V\:? \end{equation}

Comment: Sure.  But again, without more context from your book it is difficult to identify what reasoning is appropriate to conclude this answer.  Also, the link I provided appears to be a full discussion of the large signal (bias) and small signal (differential) topics to include modeling techniques should you seek a deeper understanding.